# Is there an OpenID php forum that can integrate with my existing profile system?

Tags: php, openid, forum

Recently, I have been building a website and I really want to have a forum integrated with it.  I have already implemented an OpenID login for my system and I would really like that to carry over to the forum.

I've been looking around at many open-source/free php forums, but I cannot find one that has OpenID integration.  Has anyone implemented this or seen any implementations?  Am I using the wrong terms when I do my searches for forum software?  I really want to avoid my users having to make 2 logins/2 profiles/2 etc. for my site and I personally think it would be a lot cleaner to have a universal login using OpenID.

I know coding my own forum would be reinventing the wheel, but I really want a single login and profile solution!

---

**Edit:**
Is it naive of me to think that a php forum would be able to use my already existing profile system in place of theirs?  Obviously the forum is expecting certain user information to be stored, but would it be better for me to convert my profile system into a forum's system instead of vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpBB has OpenID support using this plugin: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpbb-openid/

Comment: Usually, you always need some sort of profile even when you login with OpenID. However, you can retrieve as much info as possible from OpenID to automatically fill in the profile. They might still have to provide some basic info though, like username, etc. If I'm not mistaken, it's the same on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I already have a profile setup with my web app, but I'd like that profile to be shared between my app and the forum app.  I guess if I need to do anything... it would be to integrate my login with the forum login?

Answer (score 2):

SMF does have it in 2.0 (or a working plugin anyway)

Comment: What about the profile?  Would they need to make another one?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mchl, SMF has OpenID built in. I have not gotten OpenID to work on my forum with any other software.